# Error trying to run ServerStart.sh for FTB Infinity 1.7

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-java-edition-server

1. I don't know much of anything about Ubuntu (which is the OS I am using, 14.04 LTS)
2. I have installed the latest version of Java (jre1.8.0_40)
3. I have never tried to run a Minecraft server before
4. I have been trying to figure this out for days. If I need to start over completely, please tell me/help me with that?

Here's the error I am currently getting:

```
running install script!
ServerStart.sh: line 4: ./FTBInstall.sh: Permission denied
make sure to read eula.txt before playing!
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using the ParNew young collector with the Serial old collector is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
We appear to be missing one or more essential library files.
You will need to add them to your server before FML and Forge will run successfully.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.run(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:25)
at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:12)
```

Comment: What does `ls -l FTBInstall.sh` tell you? I suspect that `FTBInstall.sh` does not have the eXecutable permission set.

Comment: -rw-rw-r-- 1 kitanya kitanya 779 Feb  4 23:09 FTBInstall.sh

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. I'll leave instructions in an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is tech support for modded Minecraft.  We only support vanilla Minecraft in regards to tech support and troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, scripts you download are almost never executable without being given permission to execute, by you. `ServerStart.sh` is trying to run `FTBInstall.sh` in order to set up your server properly, but it can't because `FTBinstall.sh` doesn't have permission from your operating system to run; without permission, it fails to run, and because it fails to run, nothing after it works properly.

To give `FTBInstall.sh` execution permission, you just need to run the 'change mode' command `chmod` on it to turn on the e`x`ecute mode bit for yourself (the "`u`ser"):

```
chmod u+x FTBInstall.sh
```

If you do an `ls -l FTBinstall.sh` now, it will show you that the `x` permission is included for you, but still off for your `g`roup (which you rarely need on) and off for `o`thers (only useful 'on' if you know what it's for and that you need it):

```
-rwxrw-r--
```

Now any program or script running under your Linux username can run `FTBInstall.sh`, including `StartServer.sh`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to remember that for future issues. :)

Comment: @AshleyMarieRoberts 'chmod' is one of those tools that once you learn it, you'll find yourself using it all the time. For more about permissions, [Tutorial Five](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/unix5.html) from the [UNIX Tutorial for Beginners](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/) is a pretty good introduction without being dense and arcane.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you again! I definitely intend to do some learning about Linux systems!